# softmaxCrossEntropy in S4TF

Tags: swift, tensorflow, image-segmentation

im experimenting with Swift for TensorFlow to do some image segmentations, lets first look at some code:

```
let (loss, grad) = model.valueWithGradient { (model: UNet) -> Tensor<Float> in
  let logits = model(batch.images)
  print(logits.shape)
  print(batch.corners.shape)
  return softmaxCrossEntropy(logits: logits, probabilities: batch.corners)
}
```

Each `batch` contains some tensors of images of tickets, and some tensors of images of the corners, hence the two references: `batch.images` and `batch.corners`

You will see, that I also print their shapes, which both come out to be: [32, 324, 324, 4]

32 being the batch size, 324*324 being the size of the images, and 4 channels for each image. 
The goal is to extract the position of the corners on the images.

I wanna use [softmaxCrossEntropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/swift/api_docs/Functions#softmaxcrossentropylogits:probabilities:) as the loss function, but it gives be the following error:

```
Fatal error: logits and labels must be either 2-dimensional, or broadcasted to be 2-dimensional: file /swift-base/tensorflow-swift-apis/Sources/TensorFlow/Bindings/EagerExecution.swift, line 300
Current stack trace:
0    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f51ab60b940 swift_reportError + 50
1    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f51ab67ccf0 _swift_stdlib_reportFatalErrorInFile + 115
2    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f51ab5a6b48 <unavailable> + 3722056
3    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f51ab5a6cd7 <unavailable> + 3722455
4    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f51ab3794e8 <unavailable> + 1438952
5    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f51ab57a5ce <unavailable> + 3540430
6    libswiftCore.so                    0x00007f51ab378c09 <unavailable> + 1436681
7    libswiftTensorFlow.so              0x00007f51a79b5f50 <unavailable> + 2899792
8    libswiftTensorFlow.so              0x00007f51a7809d10 checkOk(_:file:line:) + 434
9    libswiftTensorFlow.so              0x00007f51a7810ce0 TFE_Op.evaluateUnsafe() + 506
10   libswiftTensorFlow.so              0x00007f51a7811550 TFE_Op.execute<A, B>(_:_:) + 323
11   libswiftTensorFlow.so              0x00007f51a781a0c2 <unavailable> + 1212610
12   libswiftTensorFlow.so              0x00007f51a792fee0 static Raw.softmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits<A>(features:labels:) + 821
13   libswiftTensorFlow.so              0x00007f51a7a6f5b0 _vjpSoftmaxCrossEntropyHelper<A>(logits:probabilities:) + 84
14   libswiftTensorFlow.so              0x00007f51a7a6f6b0 AD__$s10TensorFlow25softmaxCrossEntropyHelper6logits13probabilitiesAA0A0VyxGAG_AGtAA0aB13FloatingPointRzlF__vjp_src_0_wrt_0 + 9
15   libswiftTensorFlow.so              0x00007f51a7ac9e10 AD__$s10TensorFlow19softmaxCrossEntropy6logits13probabilities9reductionAA0A0VyxGAH_A3HXFtAA0aB13FloatingPointRzlF__vjp_src_0_wrt_0 + 444
16   libswiftTensorFlow.so              0x00007f51a7b48f64 <unavailable> + 4550500
17   libswiftTensorFlow.so              0x00007f51a7ac9a60 AD__$s10TensorFlow19softmaxCrossEntropy6logits13probabilitiesAA0A0VyxGAG_AGtAA0aB13FloatingPointRzlF__vjp_src_0_wrt_0 + 616
Current stack trace:
    frame #14: 0x00007f516f9a3c45 $__lldb_expr162`AD__$s15__lldb_expr_16110TensorFlow0C0VySfG02__a1_B4_1354UNetVcfU___vjp_src_0_wrt_0(model=<unavailable>, batch=<unavailable>) at <Cell 25>:17
    frame #21: 0x00007f516f99b941 $__lldb_expr162`main at <Cell 25>:13:34
```

I understand that the inputs needs to be 2D, but I dont know how to handle that. I cant help but notice, that [the Python version of the same function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) has a parameter `alongAxis` and wonder what I would do in S4TF to set a specific axis.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @magnuskahr I can suggest you get in touch at `/tensorflow/swift-apis` under 
[Issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/swift-apis/issues/) and the development team can look at it as soon as they can.

Also, I searched through closed and open Issues for `softmaxCrossEntropy` and came across a discussion here under [`/swift-apis/issues/422`](https://github.com/tensorflow/swift-apis/issues/422) which you may find interesting.

You can also post your questions in the official Swift for TensorFlow Google Group [here](http://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!forum/swift).